# setting a TextField's defaultTextFormat from a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

Thought this would work...

```
var bFormat:TextFormat, bStartText:TextField, bQuitText:Textfield;

bFormat = getFormat();

bStartText = getText("Start");
bStartText.defaultTextFormat = bFormat;

bQuitText = getText("Quit");
bQuitText.defaultTextFormat = bFormat;

stage.addChild(bStarText);
stage.addChild(bQuitText);

function getFormat():TextFormat {
  var bFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  bFormat.font = "Arial";
  bFormat.color = 0X000000;
  bFormat.size = 28;
  bFormat.align = "center";
  return bFormat;
}

function getText(sText):TextField {
  var bText:TextField = new TextField();
  bText.text = sText;
  bText.x = -4;
  bText.y = 4;
  return bText;
}
```

Both text fields show up on the stage, however I do not get any of the formatting specified in getFormat(). I've put the code from getFormat() in the main code (not as its own function) and it works fine. Am I passing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultTextFormat` needs to be set before you change the `text`. Since you are setting the `text` of the TextField inside getText it doesn't have any effect.

Try this :

```
var bFormat:TextFormat, bStartText:TextField, bQuitText:Textfield;

bFormat = getFormat();

bStartText = getText("Start",bFormat);

bQuitText = getText("Quit",bFormat);

stage.addChild(bStarText);
stage.addChild(bQuitText);

function getFormat():TextFormat {
  var bFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  bFormat.font = "Arial";
  bFormat.color = 0X000000;
  bFormat.size = 28;
  bFormat.align = "center";
  return bFormat;
}

function getText(sText:String, tf:TextFormat):TextField {
  var bText:TextField = new TextField();
  bText.defaultTextFormat = tf;
  bText.text = sText;
  bText.x = -4;
  bText.y = 4;
  return bText;
}
```

If you want to change the format of a textfield that was already set you can use `setTextFormat` on the `TextField` class.

Comment: +1 ic... Didn't notice before that it required to be set prior to changing text. Thanks!